# Tutorial for those who know Vim but want to learn Emacs as well

Tags: vim, emacs, documentation

I would like to find a resource listing all the Emacs equivalents (for performing various common tasks or using features in common to both editors) for the Vim commands/features that I know well.

Comment: I won't dare to claim this is a wrong approach, but be prepared that it may not work. Emacs and vim are very different so learning by analogy may not work, just like you can't learn Linux by analogy with your previous Windows experience. Much better to start from scratch, your will to learn, to read documentation and ask questions about emacs is much more important than your vim experience.

Answer (score 6):

Google for "emacs for vi users" The first 3 links are all tutorials which will do this for you.

http://www.elmindreda.org/emacs.html
http://grok2.tripod.com/
http://bradbeveridge.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/how-a-vim-user-converts-to-emacs/

etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late for you but there's [a guy](http://vimeo.com/timvisher) doing a video series called [**VimGolf in Emacs**](http://vimeo.com/26011936).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using hyperpolyglot for this purpose...

http://hyperpolyglot.org/text-mode-editors