# Where to find non-boring tutorial/book about Emacs for users familiar with Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   <s>[I'm an Emacs user. How do I learn Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/131298/im-an-emacs-user-how-do-i-learn-vim)</s>

Emacs is said to be good environment to program Lisp-based (and not only) programming languages.

However when I try to work in Emacs (being already familiar with Vim) I feel stuck in some slow mode unable to really do things and not knowing how and where to look up what keys I need to press to do this and that. For example, I have just tried to open and edit my program in Emacs and can't do it well:

```
1. How to move between panes from keyboard. How to resize them?
2. How to open multiple tabs from console (gvim *.clj -p)?
3. How to cut from opening parentheses to the closing one and paste it somewhere?
4. Why complementary bracket does not get highlighted when I select this one?
5. How to close the lower pane? (And how they are called in emacs)
6. How to undo many times in a row ("C-x u C-x u C-x u" is not convenient at all)
7. Why "Undo" sometimes turns to "Redo!"?
8. How to search? How to search&replace by regex? Will it highlight the search results?
9. How to jump between '(' and ')', '[' and ']' and so on?
10. How to auto-complete based on words in open files (like Ctrl+P in Vim)
```

Usual Emacs Tutorial explains is about moving cursor and typing text and is not that I want (just cursor keys and GUI menu items seem to satisfy that basic needs). Looking up every single feature (like in the list above) is also tiresome and uninteresting. What is a Good Way of learning Emacs?

Comment: The question mentioned in "Possible Duplicate" is about the reverse. [This one](http://superuser.com/questions/240723/tutorial-for-those-who-know-vim-but-want-to-learn-emacs-as-well) is closest, but tutorials linked there are only for basic things that can be found easily, not about more advanced features.

Comment: Yeah, I had flagged and listed that as a dupe, I'm chalking it up to Comprehensional Dyslexia...my apologies.

Comment: This should be reopened, then closed again as either "not constructive" or "off topic".  A question like this should be closed, but the current close reason is misleading.